# Round corners of UIbutton iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am creating an application with a row of buttons. I want to set the round corners for first button and the last button. First button with left corner and last button with right corner. I am using the following code.

```
//Following code from viewDidLoad function
    test_1.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], radius: 20);
            test_10.roundCorners([.TopRight, .BottomRight], radius: 20);

extension UIView{
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

My output is like the following screenshot

[image]

`Note:` Abobe screenshot from `iphone6 plus`

My ipad2 screenshot like this

[image]

Please someone help me to find the issue.

EDIT:

My required output need to be like this

[image]

Please leave the color and cross symbols.

Comment: Check my edit. That is the required outuput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually the solution is pretty simple. I just move the code inside of `viewDidAppear()` everything works fine now.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);
        test_1.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], radius: 20);
        test_10.roundCorners([.TopRight, .BottomRight], radius: 20);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use absolute values - use relatives for rounding corners or change your radius accordingly to

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale
```

Hope, you understood the direction. Your 20px are not the same on iphone6plus with Retina 3x and iPad 2 2x.